# Typescript define type for method argument

Tags: typescript, types

I have a company object, that looks like this:

```
{ 
 tracking_hours: {
  open: '8:00',
  close: '20:00'
 }
}
```

I use it to set values this way:

```
set({
 openTime: setTime(company, 'open_time'),
 closeTime: setTime(company, 'close_time'),
})
```

I need somehow set a type for company in `setTime` function

```
export function setTime(
    company: {
        tracking_hours: null | any
    },
    type: string,
): number | null {
    if (company.tracking_hours) {
        if (company.tracking_hours[type]) {
            const time = Number(company.tracking_hours[type].split(':')[0])

            if (time) {
                return time
            } else {
                return null
            }
        }

        return null
    }

    return null
}
```

How can I replace `any` with its actual type?

Comment: `tracking_hours: null | { open: string, close: string }`?

Comment: @VLAZ `TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ open: string; close: string; }'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ open: string; close: string; }'.`

Comment: So, what do you want to do, exactly? Allow any strings for keys of `tracking_hours` or restrict the values of `type` to be the kets of `tracking_hours`? Or something else? Note that right now you're passing in `"open_hours"` for `type` but the key found on the object is `open`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by

- Creating a separate type for the `Company`
- Using `keyof` to indicate the correct type for `type`

```
const company = {
  tracking_hours: {
    open: "8:00",
    close: "20:00",
  },
};

interface Company {
  tracking_hours: {
    open: string;
    close: string;
  };
}

function setTime(
  company: Company,
  type: keyof Company["tracking_hours"]
): number | null {
  const time = Number(company.tracking_hours[type].split(":")[0]);

  return time ?? null
}

setTime(company, "open");
setTime(company, "close");
```

Note, I've simplified some of your code because

- You don't need to check for the presence of `company.tracking_hours` or `company.tracking_hours[type]` - TypeScript guarantees it will they will always be present because of the types that have been specified in the function signature
- You only need to `return null` once, since all the other cases would have dropped out of the respective blocks and hit the final return statement anyway.